# Match bits and after that read 16 bits and store to new variable

Tags: java

String bin = Long.toBinaryString(i);
System.out.println(bin)

Result is: 11000000000000000000000001**11010010**0001101110110001000000001
Every time I get this binary string or another where the length is different I have a constant value which is **11010010**, I want to match it and to read 16 bits after that matched binary string.

The result in the end should be **0001101110110001**

I think it's about regular expression.

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried so far? I think using [`indexOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf-int-) and [`substring`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-int-) should be sufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a basic `indexOf` & `substring` question. Did you try a little something like below?

```
String s = Long.toBinaryString(432345579867562500l);
int i = s.indexOf("11010010");
String subStr = null;
if(i>0){
    subStr = s.substring(i+8,i+8+16);
}
System.out.println(subStr);

//0001101110110001      //output
```

Comment: i guess you should put i==0 instead of i>0

Comment: @NawnitSen: `indexOf` returns `-1` if the substring is not found, so it should be `i >= 0`. Also `substring` might cause a `IndexOutOfBoundsException` if `i+8+16` would be larger than `s.length()`.

Comment: Yeah.. Totally agree length check is also required

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using either `regular expression` or `string functions`.

**Using RegEx :**

```
String bin = "11000000000000000000000001110100100001101110110001000000001";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*" + match + "(.{16}).*");
    Matcher m = pattern.matcher(bin);
    if (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
        // O/P : 0001101110110001
    }
```

**Using String Functions :**

```
String bin = "11000000000000000000000001110100100001101110110001000000001";
        String match = "11010010";
        int index = bin.indexOf(match);
        if(index!=-1) {
            String newString=bin.substring(index+match.length(),index+match.length()+16);
        System.out.println(newString);
        }
```